Microsoft Visual C++ 2022 X86 Minimum Runtime Error (Redlist14, specifically vc_runtimeMinimum_x86.msi) During Installation
I'm encountering a persistent error while trying to install Microsoft Visual Studio. The installation fails with the following message:

Microsoft Visual C++ 2022 X86 Minimum Runtime - 14.36.32532 missing

specifically referring to redlist14.
System Info:

Windows 11, 64-bit
Visual Studio Version: Community 2022

First, I'd get the error that it can't find the specific file in the filepath for the cache, and then I tried to solve it by reinstalling/restarting my pc.
I removed all redistributables and when trying to install the latest redistributable version I got the same exact error.
My friend tried sending me the file from his cache and it still didn't work, with the error

[file path] is not a valid installation package for the product Microsoft Visual C++ 2022 X86 Minimum Runtime - 14.36.32532. Try to find the installation package 'vc_runtimeMinimum_x86.msi' in a folder from which you can install Microsoft Visual C++ 2022 X86 Minimum Runtime - 14.36.32532


specifically referring to redlist14 – it's redist (short for redistributable), not redlist.

If you download and  install this vc++ package manually from here then repair your VS, will the issue persist?

Looks like  that your computer is missing a required component of the Microsoft Visual C++ runtime library. For this issue, here are some suggestions to troubleshoot:

Download, run this tool, select Uninstalling, try to uninstall following runtimes.

Microsoft Visual C++ xxxx Xxx Additional Runtime – xx.xx.xxxxx

Microsoft Visual C++ xxxx Xxx Debug Runtime – xx.xx.xxxxx

Microsoft Visual C++ xxxx Xxx Minimum Runtime – xx.xx.xxxxx


Download and  reinstall the Visual C++ Redistributable package from here.

Run Visual Studio Installer as administrator and try to repair your VS.

If not work, you can also collect setup log files generated during installation and then search detailed error messages to analyze the cause of the issue.
(1) download Microsoft Visual Studio and .NET Framework log collection tool
https://aka.ms/vscollect
(2) run Collect.exe in  an administrative command prompt
The tool generates a vslogs.zip file in your %TEMP% folder, typically at C:\Users\YourName\AppData\Local\Temp\vslogs.zip.
For more information, please refer to: Troubleshoot installation or upgrades - Visual Studio (Windows) 


